# Удаление записей из таблице по параметру

Tags: access, vba, sql

Здравствуйте, товарищи знатоки. Продолжаю практику в Accesse и на этот раз мне пришлось делать приложения на VBA. Особо его не знаю, ибо работаю в нём второй раз в жизни. Сделал я приложение, которое должно собрать данные из формы и удалить запись из таблицы.

Алгоритм работы прост и банален:
В форме 3 поля для параметров (Важно заполнить одно из полей), в зависимости от поля формируется условие отбора и должен выполнится SQL запрос на удаление.

```
Dim where As String, action As Byte, sql_del As String

Sub on_Click()

If Me.kod <> "" Then
    where = "[Код заказчика] = '" + Me.kod + "'"
    action = MsgBox("Удалить заказчика с кодом " + Me.kod + "?", 36, "Предупреждение")

ElseIf Me.name2 <> "" Then
    where = "[Фирма] = '" + Me.name2 + "'"
    action = MsgBox("Удалить заказчика из фирмы " + Me.name2 + "?", 36, "Предупреждение")

ElseIf Me.contface <> "" Then
    where = "[Контактное лицо] = '" + Me.contface + "'"
    action = MsgBox("Удалить заказчика, контактное лицо которого " + Me.contface + "?", 36, "Предупреждение")
Else
    MsgBox "Вы не ввели ни один из параметров", 0, "Ошибка"
End If

If action = 6 Then
    'MsgBox where, 0, "Сообщение"
    sql_del = "DELETE FROM [Заказчики] WHERE " + where + " "
    DoCmd.RunSQL sql_del

End If
```

End Sub

Программа вроди и работала, пока дело не дошло до выполнения запроса. Редактор ругается и говорит что ошибка здесь:

**DoCmd.RunSQL sql_del**

В мануалах и примерах я видел использование сего объекта и его свойства, но у меня вот не работает. Прошу вас, уважаемые гуру, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Сам нашёл проблему. Конфликт типов данных в строчке:

where = "[Код заказчика] = '" + Me.kod + "'"

Ибо поле то числовое, а здесь обрабатывается как строка. Привычка блин от php осталась не следить за типами. Там собственно в запросы так и делал. Спасибо msi за внимание. Решил заменив эту строку на:

where = "[Код заказчика] = " + Me.kod

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в отладчике, как выглядит строка запроса на удаление.

Comment: sql_del = "DELETE FROM [Заказчики] WHERE [Код заказчика] = '4' "

Вот так

Comment: Ах да, совсем забыл о главном. Когда программа доходит до этой строчки вылетает с ошибкой: "Несоответствие типов данных в выражении условия отбора". Что собственно окончательно меня путает. Переменная sql_del - строка, переменная where тоже строка.

Comment: 1. Если [Код заказчика] числовой, то уберите апострофы - просто 4.
2. Попробуйте исполнить этот запрос непосредственно из Access.